# .htaccess единая точка входа

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при указании в урле любой ссылки (например, localhost/example) всегда перенаправляло на localhost/index.php, но в адресной строке так и оставалось localhost/example?

Answer (score 1):

вот так можно через htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^localhost/example$    /localhost/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^localhost/example$    /localhost/index.php?task=example [QSA,L]
```

вторая строка - пример как можно передать параметр дополнительный

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```